# Trying to get rid of "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith' " when using while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

The "for loop" below successfully prints out all the lines starting with "From" from a text-file:

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('From:'):
        print(line)
```

Now I am trying to replicate the result using "while loop" as shown below:

```
line_count =0       
line =0  

for i in fhand:  
    line_count = line_count +1
print("Total lines:", line_count)
        
while line < line_count: 
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        print(line)
    line = line +1
```

RESULT: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The `startswith()` function can not be used on integers (you initialized `line` as an integer')

Comment: could you explain what you want your modified code to output?

Comment: Thanks Vedank. I want the code to display the list of lines starting with "From". 
The "for loop" already mentioned did that successfully.

Comment: Okay, I see where I went wrong and I've adjusted the code to the below.
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')

line_count =0       
count =0
  
for line in fhand:
    line_count = line_count +1
#print("Total lines:", line_count)
        
while count< line_count: 
        if line.startswith('From:'): 
            print(line)
        count= count+ 1

Now, although there is no more error, I am now getting a blank output.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code the line corresponds to the line of .txt which would be a string value.

```
fhand = open('mbox-short.txt') 
for line in fhand: 
    if line.startswith('From:'): 
       print(line)
```

Whereas in the other code you are declaring line as int value:

```
line =0
```

EDIT:
Generally for loop is most efficient here rather than while. But if at all you need to try using while loop it would be like this:

```
fhand = open("mbox-short.txt", "r")
# readlines() returns a list of strings on each line of .txt
lines = fhand.readlines()


# Calculate the number of lines
line_count = len(lines)

line = 0
while not line >= line_count:
    # Print each index element from the list which are lines from .txt
    print(lines[line])
    line += 1

fhand.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Neeraj. Okay, so I've tried to modify the code by adding another variable "count"

fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')    
line_count =0       
count =0

for line in fhand:
    line_count = line_count +1
print("Total lines:", line_count)

while count< line_count:    
    if line.startswith("From"):
        print(line)
    count= count+ 1

What I've tried to do is let the console use the "line" item already initialized in the previous "for" loop, but now, I don't get the error and I don't get any results... I get a blank output.

Comment: why do you want to use while loop here? in this you need to access line of the result which you get after opening the .txt in read mode.Anyway i've edited the response and included if at all you need to use while loop instead of for

Comment: Thanks Neeraj, i just wanted to verify that whatever the for loop can do, so can the while loop. But I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: glad i could help :) let me know if you need more details on your query

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `line=0` should be replaced with `line1=0`

Comment: Okay, thanks Engr1hmh, i've changed the assignment from line =0 to count= 0 instead. 
Now in addition to "count" variable I have modified the while block to below. 

while count< line_count:    
    if line.startswith("From"):
        print(line)
    count= count+ 1

Now i don't get any output whatsoever. It's quite strange. I expect the print line statement to print all the lines with the string "From".

Comment: You need this complete line `for line in fhand: if line.startswith('From:'): print(line)` after `while count< line_count:`

Comment: Thanks Engr1hmh, I already mentioned that there is a "for" loop that works for this exercise:

fhand = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith('From:'):
        print(line)
The above gives me the results i need hassle free.

Now I'm looking to use the while loop by itself to print my output...except this is a task meant for the for loop alone.

Comment: Now I got it, in this line of your code `while line < line_count: if line.startswith("From:"): print(line) line = line +1` replace `line` with `i`